# rsync --update to ext disk copies unchanged files

Tags: macos, rsync

I am using rsync to make a backup of my user account on my Mac:

rsync -aXuv --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filterAll' . /Volumes/externalDisk

If I then run it again, several unchanged files are backed up again. Example files include things like the Contents directory of some .app packages, of apps in development that I have not run in years. The rsync output lists only the directory, not any of the files therein.

I have run "ls -l" on the files (directories) that rsync erroneously thinks need to be backed up, and compared that to the same on the backup disk. I don't see any differences, making me wonder what rsync sees that I do not. I have tried the -v (-v -v -v) and -i options in hopes that the more verbose output would explain why rsync thinks these files need to be backed up. I don't see anything to that effect.

I wish to use the external backup disk as a backup, of course, but also to keep 2 macs in sync. I want to run rsync with the --dry-run (aka, -n) option to verify what is being copied as a sanity check, so having rsync copy unchanged files adds a lot of noise to that effort.

Thank you,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

rsync was copying files that had an invalid group ID (admin). I changed the group ID on the source files to "staff", and rsync no longer copies them every time I run it.